# Move or browse photos and email attachments from within Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

We used to save our files in emails as an attachment, and pictures in a Picasa Web Album. Can we also browse those things from within Google Drive. If not, can we move these files to our Drive?

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about the Google Drive SDK, but rather about the Google Drive user interface.  It's not a programming question, and therefore doesn't fit in Stack Overflow.

That said, I will double check if this is a feature we are working on with Google Drive.

Comment: This is not really an answer, but you're right. I voted to move this question to SuperUser.